Unified Kernel Image (UKI)
Knows any one a way to create Unified Kernel Image (UKI) using Ubuntu 22.04?
For Ubuntu 24.04 the package "systemd-ukify" is available but not for 22.04.
I would like start Ubuntu directly via UEFI.
